# Is there a classification of numbers $k$ such that $n^k+k^n$ is not prime for all $n\geq 2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Say a number $k$ is *cool* when the number $n^k+k^n$ is not a prime for all $n \geq 2$.

> Question 1: Is there a classification of cool numbers?

For example $k=2$ or $k=15$ are not cool but $k=4$ is cool. Do you know some other cool numbers?

Note that $n^4+4^n=(n^2-2^{(n+1)/2}n+2^n)(n^2+2^{(n+1)/2}n+2^n)$ for odd $n$ and for even $n$ the number $n^4+4^n$ is even and thus $k=4$ is cool.

> Question 2: Call $k$ eventually cool when $n^k+k^n$ is prime only for finitely many $n \geq 2$. Is there a classification of eventually cool numbers?

Do you know eventually cool numbers that are not cool?

Comment: It would help if you show the general factors showing that $k=4$ is cool. Maybe, this can be generalized.

Comment: @Peter Ok, I added it.

Comment: Honestly, it seems to be that kind of question without a hope to be solved..

Comment: Is this a textbook exercise? a contest question? an online challenge? Or is this a question you've devised yourself? That is, is there any reason to believe the question has a reasonable solution?

Comment: I think, in some cases there is a prime but too large to be detected.

Comment: $k=6$ is for example a hard case. Or do I overlook a forced factorization ?

Comment: @Blue This is just a random question that came to my mind. I agree that a complete solution might be surprising, but partial answers are also welcome.

Comment: @Peter Yes, it seems $k=6$ is the first non-trivial case.

Comment: @OscarLanzi $24^5+5^{24}$ and probably $1036^5+5^{1036}$ are primes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyland_number and various links there will be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly all numbers of the form $4^{2m+1}$ are cool.  When $n = 2h+1$ is odd render

$n^{4^{2m+1}}+(4^{2m+1})^n=a^4+4b^4$

$a=n^{4^{2m}}$

$b=2^{h(2m+1) + m}$

And apply the (Sophie Germain) factorization noted in the question for the specific case $k=4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $GCD(n,k) = g \ne 1$, $n^k + k^n$ is never prime because

$$n^k + k^n = g\bigg({n^k + k^n \over g}\bigg)$$